# Principle to Pick / Refer type from other interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have a type that are defined for response data

```
interface ResponseType {
Data: {
  id: number
  name: string
}[]
}
```

And I will post an update api based on the id that comes directly from response api, so I wrote the type:

```
interface PayloadType {
id: ResponseType['Data'][0][id]
name: string
}
```

My question is:

1. Should I directly reference the type from ResponseType? I'm thinking as id comes from response.  If the type of response is being changed someday, I can directly infer that change to my paylaod and avoid repeating myself.
2. Why should I use [0] to get the type, is there an official explanation on that, can I use [100] ?
3. Is there an official docs that encourage/discourage this practice?

Comment: 1. Might be opinionated or use-case dependent. 2. When index accessing arbitrary types you should use `array[number]`. `array[0]` infers the first array item in particular. There is no difference in the inferred type but it is confusing and misleading 3. Probably not as this heavily depends on how you use it.

Comment: Please [edit] this to clearly [ask a single primary question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/511366), or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."